# Problem converting an HTML theme into angular

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

I am gonna try to explain my problem with my poor english.

I have bought a HTML template on ThemeForest and i am trying to implement this on my angular application. The theme bought is (https://themeforest.net/item/helpo-fundraising-charity-html-template/25352375).

I have choose the homepage i want (homepage 3) and pasted the html into my index.html. It was working perfectly. After this, i have started making the normal procedure on angular applications and sending this contents of index.html to appcomponent and used  on index.html.

Ps: The style refference and scripts were not moved to appcomponent.

For my surprise it is not working and i really don't understand why and what should i do. I am gonna send pictures to better show what i am trying to say.

**THAT IS MY INDEX.HTML BEFORE CHANGES. IT IS WORKING 100%**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="description"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="keywords"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <title>Helpo HTML Template</title>
        <!-- styles-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css"/>
        <!-- web-font loader-->
        <script>
            WebFontConfig = {

                google: {

                    families: ['Quicksand:300,400,500,700', 'Permanent+Marker:400'],

                }

            }

            function font() {

                var wf = document.createElement('script')

                wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js'
                wf.type = 'text/javascript'
                wf.async = 'true'

                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]

                s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s)

            }

            font()
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
CONTENT HERE
        </div>  
        <!-- libs-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs.min.js"></script>
        <!-- scripts-->
        <script src="js/common.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOW, THAT IS MY INDEX.HTML AND APPCOMPONENT AFTER CHANGES. IT IS NOT WORKING**
**INDEX.HTML (with the references but without content)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content="description"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="keywords"/>
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> -->
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/> -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico"/>
  <title>Vaquinha Animal</title>

  <!-- styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.min.css"/>
  
  <!-- web-font loader-->
  <script>
    WebFontConfig = {

      google: {

        families: ['Quicksand:300,400,500,700', 'Permanent+Marker:400'],

      }

    }

    function font() {

      var wf = document.createElement('script')

      wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js'
      wf.type = 'text/javascript'
      wf.async = 'true'

      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]

      s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s)

    }

    font()
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- libs-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/libs.min.js"></script>
  <!-- scripts-->
  <script src="assets/js/common.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**APPCOMPONENT.HTML**

CONTENT HERE

I would like to convert my html theme into angular application.

Comment: You will need to find tutorials for that. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=html+into+angular